# Tools for Design Pages and master pages in SharePoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint-2013, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

I recently install Sharepoint 2013 on a server and I want to change the presentation of my site by modifying pages and master pages.

In Sharepoint 2010 we can modify master pages easily using Sharepoint Designer 2010.

The problem is Design view remove from Sharepoint Designer 2013...and recently **I DO NOT UNDERSTAND MICROSOFT.**

Can any one introduce me some reference how I can change SharePoint 2013 page design? Can we modify existing SharePoint master page by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Visual Studio to change SharePoint 2013 master pages. You can also use Notepad. Basically, any text editor will do, and you no longer have to use SharePoint Designer in order to edit a SharePoint 2013 master page. With tools like Visual Studio or Dreamweaver you get a WYSISYG interface.

This Technet blog post describes how to use Dreamweaver and Design Manager http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/27/using-dreamweaver-and-design-manager-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Here is anther walk-through with Dreamweaver and Design Manager: http://oztripwire.blogspot.co.nz/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-branding-master-and.html

Comment: thanks dear @teylyn.How I can use VS to branding my master page? Do you mean that I just drag and drop master page file on VS? If I do this master page styles don't apply. thanks

Comment: You can use VS as one of the many HTML editors. You most certainly can NOT just drag and drop anything, just because you use VS. SP 2013 Master pages can be designed with any HTML capable editor. But you will need to do the hard yards yourself. Use VS or Dreamweaver as a WYSISYG tool for the HTML page elements. Then add the SharePoint ASP.Net controls into the code manually, as described in the links posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any editor of your choice with sharepoint 2013. Activate the publishing features to get the Design manager feature available under site settings.
You can visit Design manager-> Upload design files and then map the location as a network drive. Then you can access your design files, master pages and page layouts etc in any editor.

For more details
http://knytesh.com/2015/10/15/getting-started-with-design-manager-in-sharepoint-2013/ to get to know how to create masterpages and page layouts without using sharepoint designer and using any editor of your choice and design manager.